# How can I declare a string value more than 20 bytes in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I'd like to declare a string value more than 20 bytes in Solidity. I use `address` type, but it only contains 20bytes. Could you tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `bytes` and `string` types.
See [Solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#dynamically-sized-byte-array):

```
bytes:
Dynamically-sized byte array, see Arrays. Not a value-type!
string:
Dynamically-sized UTF8-encoded string, see Arrays. Not a value-type!
```

> As a rule of thumb, use bytes for arbitrary-length raw byte data and
>   string for arbitrary-length string (utf-8) data. If you can limit the
>   length to a certain number of bytes, always use one of bytes1 to
>   bytes32 because they are much cheaper.